# Natural candidates for energy function of knots in $S^3$?

Tags: mathematical-physics, knot-theory, statistical-mechanics, topological-quantum-field-theory

Let $K\subseteq S^3$ be a knot.

In real-life, knots (like protein chains) $K$ moves around stochastically, and experimentally the lowest energy/highest entropy states are particularly simple from a knot-theoretic point of view (see e.g. [BOS] or [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3F-S9mJmGU&ab_channel=BrennanSprinkle)).

**Question 1:** What are some natural candidates(s) for an energy function $E(K)$, explicitly?

The following is more of a physics question:

**Question 2:** Does the partition function $\mathcal{Z}=\int_K e^{E(K)/T}$ define a Statistical Field Theory? If so, in what dimension- three ($=\dim \mathbf{R}^3$), two ($=\dim \mathbf{R}^3-\dim K$) or infinite ($=$ dimension of space of possible $K\subseteq\mathbf{R}^3$'s)? Why?

In particular, if so it seems confusing to me that you can take SFT, designed to model statistical properties of large numbers of point particles, and apply it to the case where you want to model the position of a *single* knot. A naive guess is that this might have to do with "line operators" in some SFT.

---

[[BOS] Baiesi, M., Orlandini, E. and Stella, A.L., 2010. The entropic cost to tie a knot. Journal of Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Experiment, 2010(06), p.P06012.](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-5468/2010/06/P06012)

Comment: Cross-posted from physics.stackexchange, where I found it difficult to get a concrete answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_energy

Comment: This includes a brief survey of a number of knot energies: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/RepulsiveCurves/index.html